# How to write the output of a particular program and save it in the file using python?

Tags: python

```
file = open("My File.txt",'a+')
for i in range(0,5):
    cdtitle = input("Enter CD Title: ")
    while cdtitle != "##":
        cdartist = input("Enter CD artist: ")
        cdlocation = input("Enter CD location: ")
        file.append(cdtitle-----cdartist-----cdlocation)
```

file.close()

> > >
> >     According to me

Comment: Which *particular program* ?

Comment: you use file.write(some_string), not append...

Comment: also you are stuck in an infinite loop, since you don't change `cdtitle` in the `while` loop

Comment: You're script has an endless loop on `while cdtitle != "##":`  also, you should use `file.write()` instead of `file.append()`, which afaik, doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Use `write` and not append.

Also concatenate the strings and don't use the minus `-` sign.

```
file.write("\n".join([cdtitle, cdartist, cdlocation))
```

The above will also put the title, artist and location on a new line within the file.

You should also reset the status of `cdstatus` so that the loop is not infinite.

```
file = open("My File.txt",'a+')
for i in range(0,5):
  cdtitle = input("Enter CD Title: ")
  while cdtitle != "##":
    cdartist = input("Enter CD artist: ")
    cdlocation = input("Enter CD location: ")
    file.write("\n".join([cdtitle, cdartist, cdlocation))
    cdtitle = "##"
```

Comment: You could also `'\n'.join` them instead of string-concatenation. :)

Comment: doing thing like that is better to simple change the `while` for an `if`

Answer (score 0):

Your script had an endless loop on `while cdtitle != "##":`.
You should use `file.write()` instead of `file.append()`, which, afaik, doesn't exist.

```
file = open("My File.txt",'a')
for i in range(0,5):
    cdtitle = input("(## to Exit) Enter CD Title: ")
    if cdtitle == "##" : break
    cdartist = input("Enter CD artist: ")
    cdlocation = input("Enter CD location: ")
    file.write("{}-----{}-----{}\n".format(cdtitle,cdartist,cdlocation))

file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
## I managed this
FileHandle = open("My File.txt",'w')
cdtitle = input("Enter Cd title: ")
while cdtitle != "##":
    cdartist = input("Enter CD Artist: ")
    cdlocation = input("Enter CD Loation: ")
    FileHandle.write(cdtitle + ':' + cdartist + ':' + cdlocation)
    cdtitle = input("Enter CD title: ")
```

FileHandle.close()

Answer (score -1):

There is a much simpler way to directly write to a file.

```
1)Save your python script as .py
2)Open command prompt where your python file is present. 
3)Type -> scriptName.py > filename.txt 
4)Press enter
```